# Getting confused to read an xml document in xslt 1.0 ? Please advice

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml.

```
<OPTIONS_MAPPING>
    <OPTION>
        <BRM>daily data option</BRM>
        <DEFAULT>N</DEFAULT>
    </OPTION>
    <OPTION>
        <BRM>EOC</BRM>
        <DEFAULT>Y</DEFAULT>
    </OPTION>
    <OPTION>
        <BRM>Autotopup</BRM>
        <DEFAULT>N</DEFAULT>
    </OPTION>
</OPTIONS_MAPPING>
```

Now, I need to loop thru all OPTION and get BRM & DEFAULT values. I have written code but don't know how to get value for DEFAULT into an variable. Please advice.

```
<xsl:variable name="docOptionsMapping" select="document('OptionsMapping.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$docOptionsMapping//BRM">
        <xsl:variable name="brmValue" select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>         
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want

```
<xsl:for-each select="$docOptionsMapping//BRM">
    <xsl:variable name="brmValue" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="defaultValue" select="../DEFAULT"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```